# Basic facebook web application session info is missing

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebooktoolkit

I made really basic facebook application, which collect permission from user to post data. Some time ago (around New year) it worked fine.
I am using http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com, and my code looks like this:

```
public partial class Facebook : CanvasFBMLBasePage
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if(this.Api.Users.HasAppPermission(global::Facebook.Schema.Enums.ExtendedPermissions.publish_stream))
```

And at this moment I am having exception:  parameter uid or session key required

As i understand, I should have some session defined by Facebook and CanvasFBMLBasePage should parse it, and make it possible to use application, but this is not happening.

My application settings (maybe I mis something):

- Canvas Callback URL:   http://www.domain.com/app/action/facebook.aspx?
- Render Method: FBML
- Also, I put my IP in server whitelist.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Have you called the "ConnectToFacebook" method in the api before calling "HasAppPermission"?

Comment: No :) I just check it is not used in samples provided